# Find LI with data- attribute and add class to child DIV

Tags: jquery

Been stuck on this for a couple of days. I'm trying to target an LI that has a specific data attribute and then add a class to the first DIV inside it.

I can target the correct LI no problem but for some reason I'm not able to add a class to the div.

I've tried numerous things to get this to work but no luck.

This is how it currently stands.

```
 if ($("[data-type*='retailers']")) {
    $(this).find(".list-label").addClass("list-retailer");
  }
```

Here's the HTML structure

```
<li class="store-listing" data-markerid="{{markerid}}" data-type="{{type}}">
<div class="list-label">{{marker}}</div>
```

Is there something noticeably wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are generalising the stuff. Can you add the full function with the event handler, pleasE?

Comment: the value of ```$(this)``` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use if condition and then find the element. simply use jquery selector to target the required first div in li and then add class to it directly:

```
$("[data-type*='retailers'] div:first").addClass('list-retailer')
```

Comment: Yes, that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @BenToms: can you create fiddle with generated markup

Comment: @BenToms: works fine https://jsfiddle.net/vg9z2dtL/ ... you did not added jquery library earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81855/discussion-between-ben-toms-and-milind-anantwar).

Answer (score 1):

Understanding from the question, I would say use this:

```
$("[data-type*='retailers'] .list-label").addClass('list-retailer')
```